# How to change the font size in the Lipics Tex file attached below

Tags: fontsize, tex-core

I am using Lipics Tex file from [here](https://submission.dagstuhl.de/series/details/5#author). What is the font size of of the main body. How can I change it to 11 at least if it is already not.

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) If you are using this class to prepare a paper for a conference that requires the use of this class, you should not change the default size of the text as specified in Section 2.4 of the documentation, "Please do not revise the provided commands and e. g., modify text size or spacings."

Comment: It looks like 10pt to me as is. If you're not doing it for submission, but just for your own purposes, you could try putting something like `\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont` right after `\begin{document}`. (The first number sets the font size; the second number the spacing between lines.)